# Как переставить элементы в списке, чтобы одинаковые значения рядом не стояли?

Tags: python, list, список, перестановка

Дан список, например: a=[1,2,3,3,4,5,5,5,6,7,8,9,9], необходимо переставить элементы списка, чтобы получилось например так: a^=[1,2,3,4,3,5,6,5,7,5,9,8,9]. Т.е. одинаковые элементы рядом не стоят.

Comment: он изначально отсотирован? и гарантировано что там такое возможно? Просто как изменить 5 5 5

Comment: "он изначально отсотирован?" -  Нет, это как пример.

Comment: что на счет гарантий возможности такой перестановки?

Comment: "Гарантировано что там такое возможно?"-Нет"; "Просто как изменить 5 5 5" – в этом и есть вопрос.

Comment: 5 5 5 думаю вы никак не переставите в таком случае и это уже не вопрос.

Comment: Почему? Например: [5,1,5,4,3,5,1,6,7,3,9,8,9]. Вот так можно.

Comment: Ваня извините. Я про случай если в заданном массиве только пятёрки.

Comment: Ну я тот пример и переставил местами (вместо 2 указал 1, отпечаток :-) ): [1,2,3,3,4,5,5,5,6,7,8,9,9] ->[5,1,5,4,3,5,2,6,7,3,9,8,9]. Короче, вот так можно решить, но как программно реализовать?

Comment: Ваня если не программировать то никогда не научишся. Я внизу указал что делать. нужно программировать. Если ошибки или какие-то конкретные проблемы выкладывайте код и спрашивайте. Писать программу за вас никто не собирается. Учится тяжело но нужно стараться и всё получится.

Answer (score 2):

1. Пробегаете по массиву и вырезаете из неги повторяющиеся элементы в другой.
2. У вас получился массив не повторяющихся и массив повторений.
3. Пробегаете по дубликатам до конца и пытаетесь вставить в любое место первого предварительно проверив соседние. Если соседний совпадают идете дальше до конца. если конец достигнут и вы не вставили элемент то перестановка не возможна.

Comment: Вы рассматриваете 2 массива? Или для каждого дубликата свой массив? Если 2 массива, то данное решение не верное! А если для каждого дубликата свой массив тоже так себе решение, что-то в этом роде уже мной рассматривался. Я подумал может есть в теории алгоритмов алгоритм, который решает данную задачу, так вот и написал тут, в надежде может кто-то знает алгоритмы для решения подобный задач.

Comment: @ИванПетров Так и писали бы это в вопросе - про теорию алгоритмов, про варианты, которые уже рассматривались, свой частично работающий код приложили. Тогда бы это был хороший вопрос - видно, человек хочет разобраться, научиться. И другим такой вопрос был бы полезен в дальнейшем. У вас же только условие задачи, что не соответствует требованиям этого сайта и выглядит как попытка решения домашки чужими руками.